# Dual booting error

Tags: windows, gpt

## I was following [These](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) instructions and i ran into a problem.

I made the partition ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbzvh.png)) but when i ran windows 7 installer and tried to install in that partition it said the Disk0 partition 3 ( the one i made with free space for windows installation ) "WIndows cannot be installed to the selected disk. the selected disk is of the gpt partition style" and all the solutions i found were to Clean the disk, and since I don't want to lose my ubuntu i don't want to do that.

### Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you  should read that: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/05/31/installing-windows-7-on-uefi-based-computer/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a 64 bit Windows installation media or an UEFI-based system, I would recommend going through the entire content of this [site](http://www.firewing1.com/comment/3029#gpttombr) including the comments. It claims successful conversion from GPT to MBR without data loss but I haven't checked it myself, so I would proceed with caution. Use this as a last resort.

But if you have a 64-bit installation media and an UEFI-based system, you should be able to change bios settings to successfully boot from GPT too. This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-laptop-with-gpt-partition) has lots of information on how to install windows 7 64 bit in an UEFI-based system. Good luck.

Comment: IMHO, your first paragraph is a bad solution. Converting the existing OS from EFI-mode to BIOS-mode booting is overkill and can easily create new problems. The screen shot shows an ESP, which strongly suggests an EFI-based computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu installation appears to be in EFI/UEFI mode, but the Windows message indicates that the Windows installer was booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. It's best to coordinate the boot modes of all your OSes when you install more than one. In your case, this means booting the Windows installer in EFI/UEFI mode. This is basically a Windows question, not an Ubuntu question, but you might start with [this page](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/05/31/installing-windows-7-on-uefi-based-computer/) or [this one.](http://woshub.com/how-to-create-uefi-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-windows-7/) Googling or asking on a Windows forum may be helpful, too.